# ASP.NET C# - Save FileStream on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, save, filestream

I got beginners question.

How to save a file stream to a file on server?!

I got this:

```
var source = Request.QueryString["src"];
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
using (Stream stream = webclient.OpenRead(source))
{
   Bitmap iconbitmap = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream));
   FileStream os = new FileStream("./asdasdasd.ico", FileMode.Create);

   var ic = MakeIcon(iconbitmap, 16, false); /// function returns an icon

   ic.Save(os);
}
```

My problem is than when I run code in ASP.NET Development Server it saves "asdasdasd.ico" into:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\asdasdasd.ico

And, when I run it on remote server got error.

I want to save it into:
www.my-web-site.com/output/asdasdasd.ico

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file from the client to a page on your server?  If so, this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: No, I do not need to upload. I need to get source image from other server/site via QueryString, convert it to an icon and save it to server. BrokenGlass solution did the job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Server.MapPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (also a `using` block for closing the file would help):

```
using(FileStream os = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("/output/asdasdasd.ico"), FileMode.Create))
{
   var ic = MakeIcon(iconbitmap, 16, false); /// function returns an icon
   ic.Save(os);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your server's path :

If memory serves me right, you can use something like :

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MyPathToSomething");
```

Note that the path string must start with the tilde character.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use code to get the website's directory and form your own file path.

See this question for how to get the website's directory.

[How to get website's physical path on local IIS server? (from a desktop app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228813/how-to-get-websites-physical-path-on-local-iis-server-from-a-desktop-app)