# How do I get the website root outside of a request?

Tags: asp.net, ninject, bootstrapping, webactivator

Inside of a request, I can use `Server.MapPath()` to access the website root. How can I access that function or otherwise get the website root without access to `Server`? I am trying to build a binding for ninject inside of `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod`.

We have tried using `Directory.GetCurrentWorkingDirectory()`, which returned something in `Microsoft Shared\Dev Server`. However, in `Global.asax.cs`, calling `Server.MapPath("")` in `Application_Start` yields the directory I would like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` returns the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at these two questions:

- [How to get website's physical path on local IIS server? (from a desktop app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228813/how-to-get-websites-physical-path-on-local-iis-server-from-a-desktop-app)
- [How to get the IIS virtual dir & web application's physical paths with C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431713/how-to-get-the-iis-virtual-dir-web-applications-physical-paths-with-c-sharp-c)